# Regarding selecting div inside second last li.how can I select that

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having three div inside particular li..now i want to select second last li which has this div 'designnone' class name
I have done till this.

```
$('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul li:nth-last-child(2)')
```

Now how can i select div inside this second last li..I want text of that div.

Pleas help me out
thanks

Comment: Please paste a sample html code for better understanding of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `eq`

**Example**

```
$('div[groupname=' + groupName + '] ul li').eq(-2)
```

**One More**

```
$('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul li:last').prev();
```

**Comment Response**

If OP wants to get `DIV` inside second last `LI` then OP can use below code.

```
$('div[groupname=' + groupName + '] ul li').eq(-2).find('div')
$('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul li:last').prev().find('div');
```

if OP want to find first div inside of it then

```
$('div[groupname=' + groupName + '] ul li').eq(-2).find('div:first')//div:last for last
$('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul li:last').prev().find('div:first');
```

and in the end to get text of that div use `.html()` or `.text()`.

Comment: What will this select..he want to select div tag inside SECOND LAST LI which has class name :- designnone....will this code do that...?? I dont think so

Comment: @Darshan well see my updated answer for that...i thought this would be enough for OP because OP already know how to use `find()`

Comment: @Darshan Do you still have any doubts dude..?